# Primeng Calendar monthNavigator property show first month as current month

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using PrimeNG 6.0.1 and I am facing the issue in Calendar Module.

In my application, I want a month & year navigator. I have added the following code in HTML file.

```
  <p-calendar [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"></p-calendar>
```

On UI It's showing the current month as January but actually, it should show October as current month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading version solves the issue

> primeng@6.0.1 has an issue which is resolved in primeng@6.1.5

Here is the link which close issue on GitHub https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/6094